# What is the difference between Sensors namespaces available for Windows Phone developers?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

There are two namespaces available for developers on Windows Phone 8 - `Microsoft.Devices.Sensors` and `Windows.Devices.Sensors`. They are almost identical. Could someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Windows.Devices.Sensors` is from Windows App store libraries, use it in WP8.

The older `Microsoft.Devices.Sensors` is from WP7 era, before the big change with WinRT stuff etc.

Use the newer one.

There aren't meant to be any differences so far as I'm aware, it is just a migration of namespaces for newer libraries. They are deliberately similar.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.Devices.Sensors is part of the [.Net API for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and is specifically for phone app development. Windows.Devices.Sensors is part of the [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) for building Windows Store applications, these applications don't necessarily have to target a Windows Phone